# simple jquery dropdownfield update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery

I have a dropdown field and input field. Everytime I change the dropdown field, the value from the `selected` dropdown field needs to update in the `total` automatically.

The value only changes when i put something in the input field. I tested it with `.change` but it doesn't work

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').keyup(function() { // run anytime the value changes

    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#id_turnover').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#id_invoiced').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#id_collected').val()) || 0;
    var fourthValue = parseFloat($('#id_otherfield').val()) || 0;
    var total = firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue; // add them together

    $('#added').html(total); // output it

    $('#added2').html(total + fourthValue); // add them and output it
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="turnover">
  <option value="20" id="id_turnover">kuzkit</option>
  <option value="20" id="id_invoiced">testt</option>
  <option value="20" id="id_collected">tetetessr</option>

  <div id="container">Total<span style="clear:both;" id="added"></span>
    <br>
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="id_otherfield" />
</select>
<div id="container2">Total + random field<span style="clear:both;" id="added2"></span>
  <br>
</div>
```

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1b2jrjy/)

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple events on multiple elements. Your closing `</select>` was wrong.

```
$('input, select').on('input change', function() { 
// run anytime the value changes
    updateTotals()
});

function updateTotals() {
    var firstValue = parseFloat($('#id_turnover').val()) || 0; // get value of field
    var secondValue = parseFloat($('#id_invoiced').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
    var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#id_collected').val()) || 0;
    var fourthValue = parseFloat($('#id_otherfield').val()) || 0;

    var total = firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue; // add them together

    $('#added').text(total); // output it

    $('#added2').text(total + fourthValue); // add them and output it
}
```

```js
$('input, select').on('input change', function() { // run anytime the value changes
  updateTotals()
});


function updateTotals() {
  var firstValue = parseFloat($('#id_turnover').val()) || 0; // get value of field
  var secondValue = parseFloat($('#id_invoiced').val()) || 0; // convert it to a float
  var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#id_collected').val()) || 0;
  var fourthValue = parseFloat($('#id_otherfield').val()) || 0;

  var total = firstValue + secondValue + thirdValue; // add them together

  $('#added').text(total); // output it

  $('#added2').text(total + fourthValue); // add them and output it
}
```

```css
* {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#container {
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
#container2 {
  clear: both;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="turnover">
  <option value="20" id="id_turnover">kuzkit</option>

  <option value="20" id="id_invoiced">testt</option>

  <option value="20" id="id_collected">tetetessr</option>
</select>
<div id="container">Total<span style="clear:both;" id="added"></span>
</div>

<input type="text" id="id_otherfield" />
<div id="container2">Total + random field<span style="clear:both;" id="added2"></span>
</div>
```